# jQuery handle button click inside a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function, click

i don't understand why a button inside my form can't be reached with my jQuery code.

```
<form action="">
    <div class="field">
        <label for='username'>Insert username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    </div>

    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary buttonRegister'>Register</button>
</form>
```

Here are my jQuery on click try codes:

```
$('.buttonRegister').submit(function(){  
    //action inside function
});
```

--------------OR----------------------

```
$('.buttonRegister').click(function(){  
    //action inside function
});
```

--------------OR----------------------

```
$('.buttonRegister').on("click", function(){  
    //action inside function
});
```

None of them worked. I'm SURE that code inside click function works because i tried to take button outside the form and it worked well.

Comment: Because the form submits, reloading the page ?

Comment: You might want to look into handling the `submit` on the form.

Comment: @adeneo i didn't think to that, thanks, i'll need to change it so, cause i need a submit without "refresh" for my php page too..

Comment: Your second code looks OK. Add evt to the function args, and do evt.preventdefault() in the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add e.preventDefault() inside before anything else.

```
$('.buttonRegister').on("click", function(e){  
   e.preventDefault(); // <<-- required to stop the refresh
   //action inside function
});
```